# iOS - Popover not working after copying project

Tags: ios, iphone, uipopovercontroller

My problem is this:
I have a project for an iPhone app with a popover which is working fine.

I copied the project and renamed all necessary folders, references, schemes etc.
Now the new app is working except for the popover.

The message I get when running on device is: "error: use of undeclared identifier '$eax' "
And the popover controller _poc appears to be nil in the debug panel, even though the item "detailsViewController" is not nil.

Here you can see how the popover controller is created and displayed:

```
- (IBAction)showPopup:(id)sender {

    if (sender == _menuButton) {
        //show table with rooms in popover

        EADetailsViewController *detailsViewController = [[EADetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EADetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
        _poc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:detailsViewController];
        [self.poc setDelegate:self];

        // the height of the popover 
        float heightOfPopover = 44 * (_rooms1.count+1) ;

        [_poc setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)/1.5, heightOfPopover) animated:YES];

        detailsViewController.rooms = _rooms1;
        detailsViewController.delegate = self;

        [self.poc presentPopoverFromRect:_menuButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];


    }
    else if (sender == _imageButton) {
        ...
    }

}
```

I am quite new with iOS so any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Make sure your NIB name is "EADetailsViewController"

Comment: Are you using ARC? When did you find that your `_poc` is `nil`?

Comment: Yes, I am using ARC. The application stops running at the line where the detailsViewController is assigned to _poc, and I can see in the debug area _poc = (UIPopoverController *) nil

Comment: Ok, I am not sure why but it worked when I changed the name given to initWithNibName from "EADetailsViewController" to "nil".


@DipenChudasama thanks for the tip.

Comment: You have to provide propper nib name, whatever it is.